# Can I tap permanents if it's not a cost?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Blinkmoth Urn has an ability that only works if it is untapped at the start of a player's main phase. It has no activated abilities.

Can I, on my turn or any other turn, tap the artifact just to tap it, so it won't become untapped until just before my main phase? Is it legal to tap a permanent even if you are not paying a cost nor resolving a tap effect?

(If possible, a citation from the rules would be helpful, as the answer affects a coworker's main Commander deck.)

Comment: It's fine! That someone else knew what to look for has happened to me a couple of times too. It doesn't mean anything bad about you.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't just tap cards on a whim. You need to either cast a spell or activate an ability that has an effect that taps the card in question, or you need to have tapping the card as a cost for some activated ability.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot tap permanents (including artifacts) unless an ability (inherent, on the card, or another card) allow you to.